# How to get memory usage of a c# application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm particularly interested in some Visual Studio plugins (or maybe built-in functionality I don't know of) that can help me with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with perfmon - can I suggest you read this article on MSDN magazine that describes auditing memory in detail:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882521.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: Still works fine for me: [Auditing Memory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882521.aspx)

Comment: me too now..my interwebnets must been having a moment.

Answer (score 0):

`System.Process` has a lot of properties you can use to analyse memory usage.

You can get a handle on the current process like this `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` or another process using one the `Process.GetProcessXXX(..)` methods